# jQuery dialog positioning auto-positioning according window size

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a problem because jQuery dialog auto-positions itself to the window size.

For example:

[jQuery Dialog example](http://jsbin.com/udobes/11/edit)

`#dialog2`

```
$( "#dialog2" ).dialog({
  position: [0,1000],
  autoOpen: false
});
```

does not correctly position to x = 0 and top = 1000 and display a scrollbar in the browser. Instead of that it is positioning itself according to the window size.

Any suggestions?

I want to position the dialog at the specified position and display a scrollbar in the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>The following is almost working for me in that the vertical position is correct but the horizontal position is broken.</strike>

**Edit:** Got a better solution (and [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qyt7r/)) that positions correctly on the left side of the window as desired.

#### HTML

```
<div id="dialog">Hello World</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
  position:{
    my:'left',
    at:'left',
    offset:'0 1000',
    collision:'none'
  }
});
```

Note: requires jQuery, jQueryUI and one of the jQueryUI themes. Essentially, the *position* options are saying "position *my* left side *at* the left of the container with an horizontal offset of 0px and a vertical offset of 1000px". The *collision* parameter instructs jQueryUI to not reposition the element if it overflows the window (see [jQueryUI position collision](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Position#option-collision) documentation)

Lastly, http://css-tricks.com/jquery-ui-position-function/ also explains what's going on with pictures :-)

Comment: Sorry it's not a complete solution. I will attempt to correct it later but losing wifi signal right now!

Comment: Thanks mate.. if you set offset: '170 1000' its working.. but what is the first 0 ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay :-) I've got a different solution that seems to work correctly for me. Was having issues with jsBin timing out on me so added a jsFiddle demo instead of updating your original demo.

Comment: Mate seriously that's awesome:) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the JqueryUI dialog is not allowed to overflow the page at all, so unless you override the Widget to allow for this then it wont be possible.

it should be within this function in the jquery-ui-VER.js under the $.widget('ui.dialog'{}) object

```
_position : function (a) {
        var b = [],
        d = [0, 0],
        e;
        if (a) {
            if (typeof a === "string" || typeof a === "object" && "0" in a) {
                b = a.split ? a.split(" ") :
                    [a[0], a[1]];
                if (b.length === 1)
                    b[1] = b[0];
                c.each(["left", "top"], function (g, f) {
                    if (+b[g] === b[g]) {
                        d[g] = b[g];
                        b[g] = f
                    }
                });
                a = {
                    my : b.join(" "),
                    at : b.join(" "),
                    offset : d.join(" ")
                }
            }
            a = c.extend({}, c.ui.dialog.prototype.options.position, a)
        } else
            a = c.ui.dialog.prototype.options.position;
        (e = this.uiDialog.is(":visible")) || this.uiDialog.show();
        this.uiDialog.css({
            top : 0,
            left : 0
        }).position(c.extend({
                of : window
            }, a));
        e || this.uiDialog.hide()
    },
```